# How to detect when two CAShapeLayers intersect and to change the color of the intersecting pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a class called `ShapeView` which subclasses `UIImageView`. Within this class, there is a `CALayer` property called `shape` which I use to define various types of complex shapes. Using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, ShapeView will translate `shape` into a `UIImage` which is then set as the `UIImageView's` image property.

Using this set up, I'm wanting to merge two shapes that intersect each other like following:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I'm setting the stroke property of each `CAShapeLayer` so that each shape has a black border. I'm wanting to make it so that if two shapes intersect each other, I can detect the part of the stroke that's inside the other shape and change the color of those pixels to `UIClearColor` so that it gives the impression that the two shapes are merging.

I'm a little confused though as to how to detect if a certain area of a `CAShapeLayer`, which has been converted to a `UIImage`, is in another `CAShapeLayer` which has also been converted to a `UIImage`. And also how to change the color of those exact pixels to `UIClearColor` (is this even possible?).

Thanks!

Comment: *"... subclasses UIImageView"* -- will these custom views also have (other) images? If not, is there a reason you're generating `UIImage` from the shape layer? *"... various types of complex shapes"* -- I think you need to show some complex shape examples, and clarify what you want the results to look like. For example, doing something the two examples here - https://imgur.com/a/JuVLotk - is fairly straightforward task.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, it's funny you mention the thing about generating UIImages because I've been considering just using CAShapeLayers. In some instances, this class will just use a user defined UIImage instead of a CAShapeLayer so I wanted to be able to accommodate both scenarios, but I think I can convert that UIImage to a CAShapeLayer somehow? Regarding complex shapes, they just might have more sides then a square or might be a circle, but nothing too crazy. The result doesn't have to be what you linked to, just want them to intersect if the user moves them together.

Comment: Still need to clarify what you're really trying to do. I added two more variations with "shapes" here: https://imgur.com/a/JuVLotk ... does that look similar to your goal?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for doing all that, yeah that's correct except for the ones with images. When this class uses an image, it will just be the image itself (no shape or stroke) and it won't have to do the merging thing I want, will be completely separate. But the other ones with the shapes merging, that's exactly right.

Comment: *"When this class uses an image..."* -- sorry, but that is confusing me. I posted an answer using a **paths** approach. Hopefully it will help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't understand what you're trying to do with **images** ... but let's look at a Path option (instead of generating a `UIImage` from each path / shape).

If you're targeting `iOS 16.0+` we can take advantage of [`CGPathCreateCopyByUnioningPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/3950968-cgpathcreatecopybyunioningpath?language=objc) (for prior iOS versions, you can find some Bezier Path libraries out there).

Quick description...

Suppose we create two rectangle paths with these *separated* rects:

```
CGRect r1 = CGRectMake(60, 20, 100, 100);
CGRect r2 = CGRectMake(200, 60, 100, 100);

CGPathRef pthA = CGPathCreateWithRect(r1, nil);
CGPathRef pthB = CGPathCreateWithRect(r2, nil);
```

If we then **add** those paths to a mutable path:

```
CGMutablePathRef pth = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(pth, nil, pthA);
CGPathAddPath(pth, nil, pthB);

shapeLayer.path = pth;
```

we get this:

[image]

Now let's change the rects so they will overlap:

```
CGRect r1 = CGRectMake(100, 20, 100, 100);
CGRect r2 = CGRectMake(160, 60, 100, 100);

CGPathRef pthA = CGPathCreateWithRect(r1, nil);
CGPathRef pthB = CGPathCreateWithRect(r2, nil);

CGMutablePathRef pth = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(pth, nil, pthA);
CGPathAddPath(pth, nil, pthB);

shapeLayer.path = pth;
```

and we get this result:

[image]

Since your goal is to "remove the overlapping lines" we can use `CGPathCreateCopyByUnioningPath` ... same overlapping rects as above:

```
CGRect r1 = CGRectMake(100, 20, 100, 100);
CGRect r2 = CGRectMake(160, 60, 100, 100);

CGPathRef pthA = CGPathCreateWithRect(r1, nil);
CGPathRef pthB = CGPathCreateWithRect(r2, nil);

CGPathRef pth = CGPathCreateCopyByUnioningPath(pthA, pthB, NO);

shapeLayer.path = pth;
```

Now we get this as the output:

[image]

I posted a sample project here: https://github.com/DonMag/CGPathUnion

[image]

[image]